# How to separate a float number in awk into two values?

Tags: awk

There is an input file with values

```
 2    0.2
   3    0.3
   4    0.4
   5    1.0
   6    1.1
   7    1.2
   8    1.3
   9    2.0
   10    2.1
   11    2.2
   12    3.0
   13    3.1
   14    4.0
   0    0.0
   1    0.1
```

Which are produces by the part of the code:

```
BEGIN{

n=4
    b=n/10
    t=0
for (k=0.0; k<=n; k++){
for (j=0.0; j<=b; j+=0.1){
arr[t]=k+j
t++
}
b=b-0.1
}
for(n in arr){
printf("  %d    %.1f\n ",n, arr[n] )}
```

The question is, how to get an output by separating the floating number. 
An expected output has to be:

```
2  0   2
3  0   3
```

and so on..

Comment: Welcome to SO, On SO we do encourage users to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do so and let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: 
`$ echo "0.1" | awk '{split($0,a,"."); print a[2]; print a[1]}'`

This should give the desired output.

Comment: Maybe `.` instead of `,`?

Comment: ah good catch, yes